# iOS In App non-renewed subscription bought multiple times

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement the in app purchase mechanism for my app and have a hard time to figure out the right way.

My app provides a service which can be used for as many items the users wants. He can add more over the time as he wish. The service is a yearly service.

From what i understood in the documentations it should be a non-renewing subscription.
The issue is that let's say a user bought the service for item A. 
After a week a wants to add a second item to the service,item B. Then when he buys it ios pops up a window and says he already bought it and asks if he wants to renew. 
This window isn't correct ! he hadn't bought the service for item B but for item A. This would confuse my users very much and i really need to avoid this.

I've looked and found also no solution to switch subscriptions, for example between a product called "Manage 1 item" to product called "Manage 2 items" which could have been a solution.

Another solution would be to create multiple in app products with the exact name and description and manage which one to buy from within the app. Would that be ok with apple ?

How should i handle in app purchase for my application needs ?

Thank you,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you read [iOS In App guide?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1) This should be first stop for you. Secondly, you cannot have two In App products with the same id, so I don't get why adding second product would prompt user about already purchased product? Could you clarify that? In general, if I buy your product, you should keep data about my purchase and i.e. block this feature, so I it will be enabled once again only when I cancel subscription/my subscription expired.

Not sure about non-renewing, but it seems quite fit for situation, I guess. You can always consider buying consumable and store somewhere information how long you enable some features. Plus, when user buys a subscription he/she cannot get money back (except few scenarios, like mistake), so once you decide you don't need it, you cancel it. This way you can detect in receipt if product expired or not, but user cannot just swap in middle time from one product to another.